# ROS Answers SE migration: About roscore

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a beginner user of ROS . So, the question is very simple one.
When we use ROS, we have to run "roscore". But I can't understand why we have to do so.
Please teach me the reason.
If there are pages which explain about this, please tell me its link.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218783/about-roscore/) by [k-fujita](https://answers.ros.org/users/24319/k-fujita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is clearly explained on the wiki page on the [Master](http://wiki.ros.org/Master) (emphasis mine):

> The ROS Master provides naming and registration services to the rest of the [nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/Nodes) in the ROS system. It tracks publishers and subscribers to [topics](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics) as well as [services](http://wiki.ros.org/Services). **The role of the Master is to enable individual ROS nodes to locate one another.** Once these nodes have located each other they communicate with each other peer-to-peer.

> The Master also provides the [Parameter Server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server).

The 'phonebook' aspect of the master can be compared to how a DNS server functions.

Note that ROS2 does not depend on a master to locate nodes, it is fully peer-to-peer.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1